# Html not linking with stylesheet

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I'm confused. I've been trying to link my home-page to my stylesheet, but no matter how many times I reload the page, it won't load the link. I'm following the book that I have, and I'm copying the link, but on the page it doesn't show up. Can someone tell me what I may be doing wrong or what I should be doing?

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You haven't provided the  information required for us to help.

Answer (score 1):

The general way to import a stylesheet to your HTML code would be like that:

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
```

Depending on how your stylesheet file is named you need to change the "styles.css" part to your filename. Consider checking the filepath again, which is important for many frameworks.